# Querying a BigQuery table with multiple nested records

Tags: google-bigquery

I’m trying to copy a table’s schema to an empty table. It works for schemas with no nested records, but when I try to copy a schema with multiple nested records via this query:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] LIMIT 0
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

BigQuery will automatically flatten all results ([see docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#nested)), which won't work when you have more than one nested record. In the BigQuery UI, click on **Show Options**:

[image]

Then select your destination table and make sure **Allow Large Results** is checked and **Flatten Results** is *unchecked*:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> SELECT * FROM [table] LIMIT 0  with Allow Large Results and Unflatten
>   Results

The drawback of above approach is that user can end up with quite a bill – as this way of copying schema will cost the whole original table scan.

Instead I would programmatically [get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get)/acquire [table schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#schema) and then [create table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/insert) with this schema